# Using Report Datasource in ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, reporting, datasource

I hope someone knows the answer to this question.

In my application I use 2 report viewer controls, inside them, the reports have a data source connection which is not shared.

My question is, can I Query the report datasource (select queries) and get response from VB.Net Code ?

I would like to do that, because I do not want to store my database credentials in my application.

Thank you in advance

Comment: sure : use a trusted connection.

Comment: Can you help me out ? let say I have a report, that has a datasource. How do I Query the database from my application using that datasource ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, mainly if your data source is a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx), but in the end, the connection to the database must be stored somewhere in your application, on this case, you will simply store it in the report, if you want to safely use your credentials you may want to encrypt them and unencrypt them when you need them.

Comment: Oke, now it is clear it works, but can you tell me how I access the data source from the application ? I mean they are already stored in a report, encrypting it would be not a problem. Only the right code to access the datasource and apply it to a DataTable is for me... Anyways Thank you for your answer :)